# how to detect an express instance?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to add some functionality on top of Express, in my own library. Here the exported function takes one parameter, `option`, whose `app` attribute is an Express instance.

```
// index.js
var express = require('express')
var defaultOptions = {
    app: express()
}
module.exports = (options) => {
    var options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options)
    var app = options.app
    // ********************
    // Here I'm wondering how to judge if `app` is an Express instance
    // ********************
    app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
        res.send('pong')
    })
}
```

user could use it like this:

```
// server.js
var express = require('express')
var server = require('./index.js')
server({
    app: express()
})
```

Comment: Should you? If it looks like a duck, walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it's likely to be an Express instance, regardless of any implementation details you would rely on to check it.

Comment: Yeah, this feels like the wrong approach but you haven't revealed enough of your goal for me to point you in a different way.